# Sending Mail using MailSender

Tags: java

I am using SimpleMailMessage and MailSender in Spring to send mail. I have configured .xml file as

```
<bean id="mailSender" class ="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl" >
        <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
        <property name="port" value="465" />
        <property name="protocol" value="smtps"></property>
        <property name="username" value="userId@gmail.com" />
        <property name="password" value="passward" />
        <property name="endoding" value="UTF-8"></property>
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtps.auth">true</prop>
        </props>
        </property>

<bean id="userRegistrationService" class="UserRegistrationService">
        <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />
        <property name="userEmailIds">
        <set>
            <value>abc@gmail.com</value>
            <value>abc@yahoo.co.in</value>
        </set>
        </property>         
    </bean>     
    </bean>
```

but I get error :

```
Failed messages: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. 
Learn more at                              
    530 5.5.1 http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 i7sm235670pbj.90
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: It probably won't matter, but you have misspelled "encoding" in the properties, it is currently "endoding".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check out the configuration guide on [Google's site](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287)? You could for example try to set the mail port as 587 if 465 causes problems.

Answer (score 0):

protocol is written smtps it should be smtp